# How to make sure Django models match the database schema

Tags: django

Is there any script out there that check whether a Django model matches the corresponding database table (after syncdb)? I need to do this before I convert to South, and my models are pretty huge, so doing it by manual eyeballing is susceptible to errors. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something automated instead of just comparing to `python manage.py sql appname`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get a diff between your model definitions and the actual database fields you could take a look at [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

Especially [`./manage.py sqldiff`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sqldiff.html)

> Django command that scans all models
>   for the given appnames and compares
>   there database schema with the real
>   database tables.
>
> It indicates how columns in the
>   database are different from the SQL
>   that would be generated by Django.
>   This command is not a database
>   migration tool. Though it might
>   certainly be of help during
>   migrations. It’s purpose is to show
>   the current differences as a way to
>   checking or debugging your models
>   compared to the real database tables
>   and columns.

Comment: @kevin_82 Glad to hear that. So it probably makes sense to mark the question solved ;-)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I set your answer as 'accepted'... Is there something else I'm supposed to do to close this thread? Thanks.

Comment: @kevin_82 Marking the answer as accepted is all that is needed (plus an upvote :P). Users can still post other answers if they want, though.

Comment: I want to add that sqldiff is buggy and does not correctly report the differences. I get a large number of ALTER TABLE recommendations for a freshly migrated database.